# Sequence of Car Value at the End of Each Year

Tags: sequences-and-series

I bought a new car for (approximately, before taxes and what not, but we'll just say...) $18,000. At the end of n years, the value of my car is given by the sequence vn = 18000(3/4)^n, n = 1, 2, 3, …..

I figured out the formula, but I am getting confused when finding the fifth term and figuring out what the value represents ... so I can figure out the value of the car at the end of each year, as obviously, with each year a car's value decreases.

Comment: I'm confused by the question. You have the formula for the value at the end of year $n$, so just substitute $n=5$ to get the value at the end of year $5$.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is:
$$ V_n = 18000 \times \left(\tfrac34\right)^n$$

So, to find out the value after 5 years, we just plug in $n=5$, and we get

$$\text{Value after 5 years} = 18000 \times \left(\tfrac34\right)^5
                             = 18000 \times 0.75 \times 0.75 
                                     \times 0.75 \times 0.75\times 0.75$$

The answer is $4272 (to the nearest dollar).

Comment: Thanks guys! I feel a little stupid now after reading up more on it ...